# What is a plausible mechanical failure that can be corrected by telekinesis?

Tags: science-based

Hello Everyone and thanks for reading. I am writing a science fiction novel and my characters are about to board a private jet - they will be leaving Virginia and flying to CERN in Switzerland. Some factions are not happy with what they are attempting to accomplish and the plane is sabotaged. Here is the important part - one of my characters is an alien with limited telekinesis ability. If something is "stuck" then he will be able to save the plane by moving it, with his mind (not the plane itself - that is beyond his ability).

So my question is: What is a plausible mechanical failure that could be induced in advance by someone on the ground who was trying to prevent them from getting to CERN, that could be discovered by the pilot/crew during flight and that my alien can correct in time to save everyone using his telekinesis ability?

In the book's plot, the alien would have to be able to see it in order to move it...I know nothing about aviation so I don't know how to make this scene at least somewhat plausible -any suggestions would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: I think the place for you to start, instead of here at WB.SE, is articles or books about how planes work, especially the concepts and the functions of all the various control surfaces- rudder, aeleron, elevator, flaps, etc.  Once you understand that, stuck flaps/ slats might be your solution.

Comment: Agreeing with cobaltduck, when push comes to shove, the *only* thing that matters on an airplane are pieces of metal which redirect air in such a way that the plane stays aloft.  The issue would not be what could go wrong and solved by telekinesis, but rather to identify the small number of things that *couldn't* be fixed by telekinesis directly controlling the control surfaces.  Depending on how strong the telekenesis is, there may not BE anything that can go wrong which can't be fixed by it.

Comment: You might be successful asking Aviation.SE for a help.  Most issues that can come up during a flight can be solved without telekenesis (they design the planes that way).  However, you might be able to convince them to provide you with examples of issues which are not solvable by a pilot, but which do not immediately kill you, giving your alien a chance to save the day.

Comment: @Cort Ammon - thank you for your response...I went there first and they directed me to here. Oh well...

Comment: @ngolden The game of hot-potato of questions between WorldBuilding.SE and some of the more concrete SE's is an ongoing balance.  I don't think anyone has the one-size-fits-all solution for that yet.  However, a lot of the grey area between them comes in the form of wording.  If you ask Aviation what a Telekenetic could do to save a plane, they'll send you here.  However, if you ask Aviation.SE for the smallest fatal mechanical failure that the pilot cannot fix from the cockpit that don't involve actually losing any parts, that could be a question they would probably accept.

Comment: There might still be some wordsmithing needed to make it a valid Aviation.SE question (e.g. they might need you to narrow it down to a specific type of plane), but hopefully a wording change like that would help bring the question most of the way towards validity on Aviation.SE.  I'd also tune the question to your telekenetic's capabilities, which I don't know.  I say "doesn't involve actually losing any parts" as a minimum -- your telekenetic can't fix a part that isn't on the airplane anymore unless they've got quite the reach. Your telekenetic might have force limits or something.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be sabotage of the aircraft's hydraulic systems.

This is a fairly simple and straightforward form of sabotage, and could easily be missed until partway into the flight when the control surfaces become unresponsive.  Although a large cut in the hydraulic system would probably be noticed by the pilot immediately, a smaller cut / leak or the weakening of a line that pops off later under load might not be noticed until mid-flight.

Once the control surfaces become unresponsive, the alien would need to use telekinesis to manipulate the control surfaces and safely land the aircraft.

Another option would be sabotage preventing the landing gear from descending and locking properly.  In this case, the alien would need to manipulate the landing gear or use their telekinesis to hold it in place until the plane has safely landed.

In the latter case, the alien having to 'hold' the landing gear in place throughout the landing could hold some dramatic tension as the effort could be arbitrarily large or small, depending on the degree of sabotage.  Additionally, the alien's telekinesis could fail midway through landing, but the crash could be minor enough for the passengers to survive.

Other failures could be a fire in an engine where the fire extinguishers have been sabotaged.

Or you could go all the way and have a missile / missiles fired at the aircraft, which your alien needs to manipulate enough that they just miss.

Comment: thanks so much for your thoughtful response. You gave me some interesting ideas to think about!